# Can someone tell me the chapter and verse of mund mala tantra where dashavatar is said to be incarnated from dasa mahavidya

Tags: vishnu, avatars, tantra, kali, dasha-mahavidya

There was a post that in mundamala tantra and todal tantra there is mention of 10 mahavidya as dashaavatar. The verses of todal tantra is already given But I need verses of mundmala tantra, chapter number and verse number with translation
Please provide it soon

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24410/647

Comment: I guess you are talking about my answer.. I will check whether the book (I'm quoting from) mentions the chapter number and verses numbers or not.