# Are there any associations between Dus (Dasha) Mahavidyas and Shreman Narayana and or Shree Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, shaktism, sadhana, dasha-mahavidya, satyanarayana

In the many manifestations of Maa Shakti as Adi ParaShakti, we encounter the Dus Mahavidyas which some practicioners in tantra sadhana consider also to perform the bhakti and the sadhana towards Maa Bhuwaneshwari and with a particular procedure.

QUESTIONS:

1. I would like to ask what exactly do Her represents and what are Her tasks as Divine Manifestation of Supreme Adi ParaShakti.

2.I would like also to ask if and when are there any relations among Her and Maa Bagalamukhi. Lastly I want to ask if are there any relationships between These Forms of Shakti and Shreeman Narayana or Shree Vishnu. Thank you

Comment: See the answer in this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24410/does-shaiva-or-shakta-agama-believe-the-dashavatar-of-lord-vishnu

Comment: Balobashi....Āpanāra tantra jñāna.... khuba mūlyabāna.... @Rickross

Comment: Anek Dhanybad ...

Comment: Ji mere sekhana talk in pvt email me please balobashi @Rickross

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relation between Dash Mahavidyas and Dashavatar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/what-is-the-relation-between-dash-mahavidyas-and-dashavatar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rickross answer:

"The Todala Tantram, which is a ShAkta Agama, talks about the 10 AvatAras of Lord Vishnu. The text also equates one MahAvidyA deity with one AvatAra.

```
The last chapter equates Vishnu’s ten incarnations with the ten Mahavidyas. Durga is the Kalki, the last of the avatars of Vishnu. He is yet to come, and when he does he will be born in Shambhala. He will ride a white horse and hold a sword which blazes like fire, bringing back to the planet harmony, according to the Agni and other Puranas. Kali’s consort is Krishna.

“Shri Devi said: Lord of gods, guru of the universe, tell me of the ten avatars. Now I want to hear of this, tell me of their true nature. Paramesvara, reveal to me which avatar goes with which Devi.

“Shri Shiva said: Tara Devi is the blue form, Bagala is the tortoise incarnation, Dhumavati is the boar, Cchinnamasta is Nrisimha, Bhuvaneshvari is Vamana, Matangi is the Rama form, Tripura is Jamadagni, Bhairavi is Balabhadra, Mahalakshmi is Buddha, and Durga is the Kalki form. BhagavatÌ Kali is the Krishna murti.” (Todala, chapter 10)
```

The page i am quoting from is just an overview of the said Tantram. I will give the Sanskrit verses tomorrow from books. Also, i am not sure about the Shaiva Agamas.

EDIT:

The Sanskrit verses from the Todala Tantram are as follows:

```
TArA devi minarupA bagalA kurmamurtikA |
DhumAvati varAha syAt chinnamastA nrisimhikA ||
Bhuvaneswari vAmanah syAnmAtangi rAmamurtikA |
TripurA jAmadagnyah syAd balabhadrastu bhairvai ||
Mahalakshmir bhavet buddho durgA syAt kalki rupini |
Swayam bhagavati kAli krishnamurtih samudbhavA ||
Iti te kathitam devAvataram dashamevahi |
```

The translation is already given above.

Now, there's difference of opinion as to this mapping. The MundamAla Tantram (which is another ShAkta Agama) gives a slightly different list as follows:

```
Krishnastu kAlikA sAkshAd rAmamurtishcha tArini |
VarAho bhuvanA proktA nrisimho bhairavishwari ||
DhumAvati vAmanah syachinna bhrigukulodbhavah |
KamalA matsyarupah syAt kurmastu bagalAmukhi ||
MAtangi bauddha ityeshA shodashi kalkirupini |
```

Here the mapping is as follows:

```
KAli-- Krishna
TArA-- RAma
Bhuvaneswari-- VarAha
Bhairavi-- Nrisimha
DhumAvati-- VAmana
Chinnamsta-- ParashurAma
KamalA-- Matsya
BagalAmukhi-- Kurma
MAtangi-- Buddha
Shodashi-- Kalki."
```

[Does Shaiva or Shakta Agama believe the Dashavatar of lord Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24410/does-shaiva-or-shakta-agama-believe-the-dashavatar-of-lord-vishnu)

Until now the most complete one.